# Combining Two Lists Based on first 6 Characters

Tags: c#, list, character, union

I have two lists (Current & New).  Current can contain 100,000+ strings each starting with a unique number.  New can contain anywhere between 50 and 200 strings each with a unique number.

If New contains a string starting with the same 6 characters it should replace the same entry in Current.  Any new entries that don't exist in Current but exist in New should be added to Current. I've considered Union, Concat and Intersect, but each only deal with the entire string.

Is there some way to compare just the first 6 characters of an item in a list and replace the entry in Current if found it exists in New?

Perhaps the easiest way to visualise the above is:

**Current**

```
123456 66 Park Avenue Sydney
```

**New**

```
123456 88 River Road Sydney
```

**The result in Current needs to be**

```
123456 88 Park Avenue Sydney
```

If `Current.Union(New, first X characters)` was possible it would be perfect.

Any suggestions on Combine the two lists without duplicates based on the first 6 characters would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your current set should likely be a `Dictionary<string,string>` of the first six and the complete string. Then you iterate New, check that it’s length is six or greater and grab the substring of the first six. If the dictionary has the key (the first six), update it with the full string. If it does not, add the substring as the key and the full string as the value. If the string has a length less than 6 than do what your business rules dictate.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected results.

Comment: Um shouldn't the result be "123456 88 River Road Sydney"?

Answer (score 0):

string.StartsWith is what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

This should do it. Note I have used two dictionaries because there might be duplicates to be replaced, if not, you can use one.

```
public static void Coder42(List<string> current, IEnumerable<string> news)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> newDict = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    Dictionary<string, string> unfound = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    foreach (var n in news)
    {
        if (n.Length < 6) throw new Exception("Too short");
        var ss = n.Substring(0, 6);
        if (newDict.ContainsKey(ss)) throw new Exception("Can't be too new.");
        newDict[ss] = n;
        unfound[ss] = n;
    }



    for (int i = 0; i < current.Count; i++)
    {
        var s = current[i];
        if (s.Length >= 6)
        {
            var ss = s.Substring(0, 6);
            if (newDict.TryGetValue(ss, out string replacement))
            {
                current[i] = replacement;
                unfound.Remove(ss);
            }
        }
    }

    foreach(var pair in unfound)
        current.Add(pair.Value);
}
```

And tested using:

```
var current = new List<string>();
current.Add("123456 a");
current.Add("123457 b");
current.Add("123458 c");

var news = new List<string>();
news.Add("123457 q");
news.Add("123456 p");
news.Add("123459 z");

Coder42(current, news);

foreach (var s in current) Console.WriteLine(s);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Gives:

```
123456 p
123457 q
123458 c
123459 z
```

Comment: Excellent. I tried it out on 2000 records and 20 records and was impressed at how it performed.  Will be trying it out on 100,000 later.